# Can I nest a "for" in an "if" in a Django template?

Tags: django, for-loop, if-statement

Just learning Django, and I'm trying to create a situation where when a template has layouts it'll list them, but if it doesn't it won't and will instead state that there are none.

I got an error message when I used only a "for layout..." statement on templates that had no layouts.

I figured things out to the point that I created an "if" statement to first check and see if the pages had layouts, and if not, an "else" statement to say that there are none.

The end result, though, is that the "for" seems to be completely ignored, and the "else" condition is applied on all pages -- whether or not they have associated layouts.

Code:

```
{% block header %}
    <h1>The name of this template? It's {{ boilerplate.name }}.</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>{{ boilerplate.content }}</p>
    {% if layout in boilerplate.layouts %}
        {% for layout in boilerplate.layouts.all %}
        <p><a href="{{ layout.file.url }}">{{ layout.user }} -- {{ layout.name }} ({{ layout.file.size }})</a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
    <p>There are no layouts for this template.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

There's obviously something I'm missing. Possibly something very simple. What am I dong wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `{% if layout in boilerplate.layouts %}` is what's wrong, but there's an easier way to achieve this than using an additional `if` tag.

[As the documentation shows](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#for-empty), you can use an optional `empty` tag to handle situations when you have no layouts. Rewriting your example code:

```
    {% for layout in boilerplate.layouts.all %}
    <p><a href="{{ layout.file.url }}">{{ layout.user }} -- {{ layout.name }} ({{ layout.file.size }})</a>
    {% empty %}
    <p>There are no layouts for this template.</p>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's much better, thanks. I need to make a habit of constraining my searches for information like this *to* the documentation, because I wasn't getting anything useful in general.

Comment: Hm. Actually, I'm now getting a ValueError when I try the empty tag... the template works for layouts that have templates, but throws ValueErrors for all the templates that do not:
Error during template rendering

In template /home/mattshepherd/customipsum/ipsum-cont/boilerplates/templates/boilerplates/content.html, error at line 16
The 'file' attribute has no file associated with it.

Comment: That looks like an issue with `{{ layout.file.url }}`, and not the `{% empty %}` tag. If a layout doesn't always have a file, then you should check for its existence before trying to render it.

Comment: I got a little help from a friend, and you're right: I needed to check for the file first.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#for-empty
Look at this tag

Answer (score 0):

To answer the subject of your question, yes, of course you can. My guess from the way you describe your problem is that there may be an issue with how you look for the layout in `boilerplate.layouts`.

`boilerplate.layouts` looks like it's a relational field. Thus, doing an `in` check on that alone may not be sufficient. In cases like this, I would recommend playing with this code in the shell, or in the view and seeing the result there, as it will greatly help debugging.

My simple guess is you need to do `layout in boilerplate.layouts.all`, but I am not familiar enough with your model, so wild guess :)

Comment: To do it with an `if` and a `for`, I think it should read `if boilerplate.layouts.all`, but as I said in my answer, that's over-complicating things really.